# Following Gatsby tutorial stuck on "unexpected use of location"

Tags: node.js, gatsby

I am getting this error in Gatsby app. My code seems to be identical to the tutorial I am following, I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. The error is

> 50:10  error  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals

There are other pages, maybe something being imported is causing a conflict. I am using node version `v11.0.0`.

The code is below:

`src/components/layout.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Img from 'gatsby-image'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

import Header from './header'
import Archive from './archive'
import './layout.css'

const MainLayout = styled.main`
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 6fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 40px;
`

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
        file(relativePath: { regex: "/bg/" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <>
        <Helmet
          title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
          meta={[
            { name: 'description', content: 'Sample' },
            { name: 'keywords', content: 'sample, something' },
          ]}
        >
          <html lang="en" />
        </Helmet>
        <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
        //**HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS HAPPENING**
        {location.pathname === '/' && (
          <Img fluid={data.file.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        )}
        <MainLayout>
          <div>{children}</div>
          <Archive />
        </MainLayout>
      </>
    )}
  />
)

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: add `location` to you component declaration 
`const Layout = ({ children , location}) => ( ...)`

Comment: could you make this as an answer and I will choose it, I literally figured this out as soon as you posted this, I wrote this late last night so was tired. Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `location` to your component declaration:

```
const Layout = ({ children, location }) => ( ... )
```